# The correct way to bind this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access 'this' inside a method that is called from a button press, where this refers to both the class and the button pressed:

```
p.myVar = 'banana';

$('.go').on('click', this._init);

p._init = function(e){
    //get the button pressed
    //get this.myVar
};
```

To do this I bind this:

```
$('.go').on('click', this._init.bind(this));
```

The above works and I can now access my var via:

```
this.myVar; //banana
```

But I can no longer access the button.

How can I access it, use e.currentTarget or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't see how using `e.currentTarget` would be harmful. It would probably be the best thing to do in this case.

Comment: Based on your question, "this" cannot refer to both the class and button pressed at the same time

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `data` argument :

```
$('.go').on('click', {myVar:'banana'}, this._init);

p._init = function(e){
    // use e.data.myVar;
    // this is the right matching clicked element
};
```

Comment: this is a bit messy, redeclaring vars

Comment: I don't think so : you pass the data you want, with the name suitable for the context of the event handler

Answer (score 0):

I presume your declaring the event listener in a closure, if so you can use a local variable and pass it that, the reference is unique to the closure and can be accessed by the function in the listener when it is called. It becomes a kind of invisible global, the reference only exists to that specific call and the listener function but is still shared.

```
function initButtons(){
var selfRef = this;
$('.go').on('click',selfRef._init);
}
```